# Slack bot throws channel_not_found error when bot is added to a new workspace and DMd

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have prepared a simple bot that returns a message on every new messag in either DMs or public channel. When installed to the primary workspace (the one that app was originally created) everything works perfect (the bot is responding to messages).

Then I did all the steps to enable Manage Distribution (in order to install slack to other workspaces). The install and redirect button are working and the Bot was successfully added to another workspace. But the problem is that whenever message is sent over DM or in a channel that this bot is invited to an error is thrown in the bot console:

```
[ERROR] bolt-app Error: An API error occurred: channel_not_found

  at platformErrorFromResult (/slack/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:56:33)

  at WebClient.apiCall (/slack/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/WebClient.js:181:56)

  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

  at async /slack/build/index.js:48:13

  at async Array.<anonymous> (/slack/node_modules/@slack/bolt/dist/middleware/builtin.js:245:9)

  at async Array.onlyEvents (/slack/node_modules/@slack/bolt/dist/middleware/builtin.js:73:5)

  at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)

  at async /slack/node_modules/@slack/bolt/dist/App.js:577:48

  at async Array.<anonymous> (/slack/node_modules/@slack/bolt/dist/conversation-store.js:67:9)

  at async Array.<anonymous> (/slack/node_modules/@slack/bolt/dist/middleware/builtin.js:274:9) {

 code: 'slack_webapi_platform_error',

 data: {

  ok: false,

  error: 'channel_not_found',

  response_metadata: { scopes: [Array], acceptedScopes: [Array] }

 }

}

[ERROR]  An unhandled error occurred while Bolt processed (type: event_callback, error: Error: An API error occurred: channel_not_found)
```

What could be the problem?

I am using BOT token with scopes: `channels:history, chat:write, commands, im:history and mpim:history`

Bot events: `message.channels, message.im, message.mpim`

Events on behalf of user: `im_close, im_created, im_open, message.channels, message.im`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

- I have tried deleting the app and setting all configurations from scratch.
- I've played around with different bot scopes